# Issue when returning a MutexGuard inside a RwLockGuard

Tags: rust, locking, mutex

I'm trying to shorten some functions in my code.

I would like to create a function such as `get_baz` so I can (slightly) simplify other functions inside `Foo` that are pretty similar to `do_long`.
My attempts have been rather unfrtuitful. I understand what I have doesn't work becase, when the scope of `get_baz` ends, the outer `RwLockGuard` drops, and thus the internal `MutexGuard<Baz>` is not valid anymore.

Is there a way to achieve this?

This is a representation of what I have. Hopefully it's accurate enough:

```rust
struct Baz {}
impl Baz {
    async fn do_mut(&mut self) -> () {
        ...
    }
}

struct Bar {
    baz: Arc<Mutex<Baz>>
}

struct Foo {
    bar: RwLock<Bar>
}

impl Foo {
    async fn do_long(&mut self) -> () {
        self.bar.read().await.baz.lock().await.do_mut().await
    }
}

impl Foo {
    async fn get_baz(&self) -> MutexGuard<Baz> {
        // TODO: I know this doesn't work, but is essentially what I have.
        self.bar.read().await.baz.lock().await
    }

    async fn do_short(&mut self) -> () {
        self.get_baz().await.do_mut().await
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think this is possible.

Comment: You can always write a macro instead of a method, even though it's not as pretty.

Comment: Feared it might not be possible, but thanks for confirming my thoughts :)

@jthulhu Interesting solution, I'll have a look at it.